# Some python related problems

Tags: python, python-2.7

[image]

I don't know where is the problem with this, I installed Python 2.7 already

Comment: Please don't link images of errors, just enter the text of the error in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you haven't installed comp62521.
You should be able to install it with this:

```
pip install comp62521
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible scenarios I can think of:

1- You did not install the package `comp62521` (or installed a wong version maybe?)

2- You have a variable called `comp62521` somewhere in your code, which is overriding the package name, hence `comp62521.statistics` cannot be found anymore.